# How can I limit the outbound traffic?

Tags: networking, server, security

I have a server running Ubuntu 22.04. They give me a monthly allowance of outbound traffic (bandwidth). When my server runs above this allowance, they do not stop the server - they let it run, and [charge me 1 cent per GB](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/billing/bandwidth/), which can reach hundreds of dollars per day.

Is there a way I can put a hard limit on the outbound traffic, so that when the limit is hit, the server simply blocks all outbound traffic from now on?

Answer (score 1):

Most network limiters I know offer bandwidth restriction per second, but your granularity is per month. I would write a script to harvest the outgoing amount from /proc/net/netstat and if it's above a threshold run an iptables rule to block all outgoing traffic except for the SSH traffic to/from my machines and run it in a cron job or system timer

Comment: Bandwidth restriction per second could also be useful in my case. How exactly can I do this?

Comment: tc and iptables have ratelimiting options, wondershaper and trickle are applications I've never used. With tc you can shape your traffic classes and add them to different queues to set priorities. It's complicated and powerful. If I have time I'll update my answer to give some examples.

Comment: Have a look at [wondershaper](https://averagelinuxuser.com/limit-bandwidth-linux/#:~:text=user%2Dfriendly%20applications.-,Limiting%20the%20bandwidth%20per%20network%20interface%20with%20Wondershaper,interface%20of%20your%20Linux%20machine)